# Where are the images/icons used in the power menu saved in Windows?

Tags: windows-10, icons

I am trying to create shortcut icons for actions like `Shutdown`, `Restart`, etc., on my Desktop, and wanted to use same icons as used by Microsoft on the power menu.

[image: screenshot of the windows power menu]

I am not sure which DLL/EXE file contains these icons. I've looked at the common ones, like `%systemroot%\system32\imageres.dll`, `%systemroot%\system32\shell32.dll`, `%systemroot%\explorer.exe`, etc., but the icons seen on the power menu are not here.

Could someone please guide me in the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked in `C:\Windows\System32\imagesp1.dll` and `C:\Windows\System32\filemgmt.dll`?

Answer (score 0):

I think they are characters from the font `Segoe MDL2 Assets`. Microsoft seems to be moving toward font-based UI elements, and away from bitmaps inside DLL’s and EXE’s.